# Creating responsive triangles with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, shapes, css-shapes

I was trying to create triangles in CSS for a responsive site today and couldn't find a good example on stackoverflow, so here's how I did it.

Comment: There is a great article by Chris Coyer in CSS-tricks.com that shows how to create more than triangles with pure CSS. http://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Comment: @sulfureous yeah, that's an awesome resource.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive triangle div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891619/responsive-triangle-div)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Making angular shapes responsive is a little tricky because you can't use percentages as `border` values in your CSS, so I wrote a couple functions to calculate the page width and resize a triangle accordingly. The first calculates the size on loading the page, the second recalculates the size as the page width changes.

CSS:

```
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $(".triangle").css({
        "border-top": windowWidth / 2 + 'px solid rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)'
    });
    $(".triangle").css({
        "border-right": windowWidth / 1.5 + 'px solid transparent'
    });
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    var windowWidthR = $(window).width();
    $(".triangle").css({
        "border-top": windowWidthR / 2 + 'px solid rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)'
    });
    $(".triangle").css({
        "border-right": windowWidthR / 1.5 + 'px solid transparent'
    });
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/craigcannon/58dVS/17/

Comment: Good... +1 for Q & A, but any idea explanation, why you are using `%` for `rgba`

Comment: also, the percentage is more than 100% ?

Comment: @Mr.Alien lol. Good spot. I think I just copied a value from photoshop and included the % by accident. Revising now.

Answer (score 6):

Reponsive triangles can be achieved with just CSS by taking advantage of padding being calculated against parent’s width to cover a big fixed-width triangle. To create an up-pointing triangle with 100% width:

```
.triangle-up {
    width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    padding-left:50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-up div {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-500px;
    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 500px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 500px solid green;
}
```

Or using pseudoelements and just one div:

```
.triangle-up {
    width: 50%;
    height: 0;    
    padding-left:50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-up:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-500px;
    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 500px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 500px solid #959595;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/3HG6d/). For the full explanation on how these work and the down, left and right pointing triangle snippets see my article on [Pure CSS responsive triangles](http://codeitdown.com/pure-css-responsive-triangles/). The CSS given is for a triangle with base-height ratio of 2. Trying to change the triangle's proportions without knowing how these triangles fake responsiveness may be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same using simple CSS

To make it responsive use it in media queries..

Try the following JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/52grj/

```
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid rgba(255%, 204%, 0%, 1);
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but you'd have to make media queries every 10 pixels to maintain a consistent design.