# How to make triangle border responsive on top side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to make Triangle border responsive. Below is the direct link to codepen. You can see the border just above the white details box . Screenshot -

[image: screenshot]

```
<!-- Features -->
<div class="section text-center">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">
            <div class="feature-box v2">
                <div class="featured-box-image">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480" alt="features" class="img-responsive">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>                      
                <div class="details">
                    <div class="hexagon"><span><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div> <!-- end .hexagon -->
                    <h4>Lorem Ispum</h4>
                    <p class="sub-text">Lorem Ispum</p>
                    <p class="text">Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum</p>
                </div> <!-- end .details -->
            </div> <!-- end .feature-box -->
        </div> <!-- end .col-sm-4 -->
    </div> <!-- end .row -->
</div> <!-- end .section -->
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBVVNo

Thanks in advance.

Note: Already tried this below solution but it didn't work since I'm using pseudo class for triangle border.
[Creating responsive triangles with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826057/creating-responsive-triangles-with-css)

Comment: Stack Overflow has both a built-in image upload feature and a built-in runnable snippets feature. Why link to external sites?

Comment: You can better use some SVGs for such graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you needed.

Cheers!

```js
function resizeTriangle() {
  var wid = document.getElementById('details').clientWidth / 2;
  var css = '.feature-box.v2 .details:before {border-left-width: ' + wid + 'px;border-right-width: ' + wid + 'px;}',
 head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
 style = document.createElement('style');

  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.id = 'myStyle';
  if (style.styleSheet) {
 style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
 style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }
  if ($('style#myStyle')) {
 $('style#myStyle').remove();
  }
  //head.removeChild(document.getElementById('myStyle'))
  head.appendChild(style);
}
$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeTriangle();
});
window.onload = function() {
  resizeTriangle();
};
```

```css
.col-sm-4 {
  margin: 0 auto;  
}
.feature-box {
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.feature-box img {
 width: 100%;
}
.feature-box:hover .details a {
 bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: 49px;
}
.feature-box .details {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -1px;
    padding: 0 71px 0 33px;
    width: 93%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
}
.feature-box .details:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -2;
    background: #ff5534;
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom right;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    -ms-transform: skew(16deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(16deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(16deg, 0deg);
}

/*-----Features-v2-----*/
.feature-box.v2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.feature-box.v2 .featured-box-image span {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: #ff5534;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: .3s;
 transition: .3s;
}

.feature-box.v2 .details:after {
 content: none;
}
.feature-box.v2 .details {
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 18px;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #1f2730;
    padding: 0 50px;
    width: auto;
}
.feature-box.v2:hover .details p.text {
 max-height: 999px;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
    color: #9b9fa3;
}
.feature-box.v2:hover .featured-box-image span {
 opacity: .9;
}
.feature-box.v2:hover .details {
 background: #fff; 
}
.feature-box.v2:hover .details.highlight h4, .feature-box.v2:hover .details h4 {
    color: #1f2730;
}
.feature-box.v2:hover .details:before {
    border-bottom: 40px solid #ffffff; 
}
.feature-box.v2:hover .hexagon {
 background: #1f2730;
}
.feature-box.v2:hover .hexagon:before {
 border-bottom: 17px solid #1f2730;
}
.feature-box.v2:hover .hexagon:after {
 border-top: 17px solid #1f2730;
}
.feature-box.v2 .details p.sub-text {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin-top: 0;
 color: #9b9fa3;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.feature-box.v2 .details p.text {
    max-height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}
.feature-box.v2 .details:before {
 content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: -50px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 0px;
    float: left;
    border-left: 184px solid transparent;
    border-right: 184px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #1f2730;
}
.feature-box.v2 .details h4 {
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
 .feature-box.v2 .details {
  padding-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
 }
 .feature-box.v2 .details p.text {
  max-height: 999px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
 }
 .feature-box.v2 .hexagon {
  display: none;
 }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- Features -->
  <div class="section text-center">
   <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">
     <div class="feature-box v2">
      <div class="featured-box-image">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480" alt="features" class="img-responsive">
       <span><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </div>      
      <div class="details" id="details">
       <div class="hexagon"><span><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div> <!-- end .hexagon -->
       <h4>Lorem Ispum</h4>
       <p class="sub-text">Lorem Ispum</p>
       <p class="text">Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum</p>
      </div> <!-- end .details -->
     </div> <!-- end .feature-box -->
    </div> <!-- end .col-sm-4 -->
   </div> <!-- end .row -->
  </div> <!-- end .section -->
```

Comment: It worked. You da man. Also I was wondering if above JS code would work for Triangle border that has been created using css3 transform skew and rotate properties as well. For eg. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmLEON

Thanks again. Really appreciated. Cheers!